# iAds displayed on my device but not on my Moms Phone iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, iad, jailbreak

I have an App submitted and approved in the App Store "Falling Stones - Avoid the Stones". I downloaded it in the App Store with my iPhone and the iAds are displayed. If I download it with the iPhone from my mom and her Apple ID, I can't see any Ads in the game. How is that possible?

Do you need any of my code?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It doesn't show Ad if your Mom's device is jailbroken

Comment: I can definitely say, its not

Comment: Add some relevant code to your question. Ads appear in your application for me.